# define struct with variable length vectors in C

Tags: c, struct

I need to declare a struct with variable length vectors..

with the solution below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S
{
  int len;
  double *x;
  double *y;
  double z;

};

int main()
{
double x[] = { 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.  };
double y[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.5, 4.0 };

//struct S myS = { .len = 4, .x = x, .y = y,  .z = 5.1 };
struct S myS = { 4, x, y, 5.1 };
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use pointers instead like `double *x` or you can set the array size to max value like `double x[10000]`.

Comment: You can't do what you are trying. C has something called flexible array member but there can only be one and it must be the last member. Further you can't set its size using an initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `struct S` to have pointers to `double`:

```
struct S {
   double  *x;
   double  *y;
   double  z;
};
```

When creating a `struct S`, first create arrays for the members to point to:

```
double SampleX[] = { 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.  };
double SampleY[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.5, 4.0 };
```

Then define the structure with members pointing to that data:

```
struct S myS = { .x = SampleX, .y = SampleY, .z = 5.1 };
```

The designated initializers, `.x =` and so on, are unnecessary if you initialize all members in order, but they are shown here as an option.

Also add some way of knowing how many elements there are. If they can vary, routines that are passed this structure cannot know how many elements there are unless they are given that information in some way, such as via another member in the structure or some argument passed to the routine.

Creating the arrays for the members to point to can be done in additional ways to the one shown above. You can use compound literals:

```
struct S myS = {
    .x = (double []) { 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.  },
    .y = (double []) { 1.1, 2.2, 3.5, 4.0 },
    .z = 5.1
};
```

or you can use `malloc` to allocate memory for the arrays. (If you use `malloc`, also use `free` to release memory when you are done with it, although that typically may be omitted when exiting the program.)

Comment: Thanks to all who helped!